# Dynamic javascript from web resource

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written a custom web control that validates some input to a textbox client-side. The associated JavaScript is an embedded resource. As part of the validation process the JavaScript displays a confirm alert box.

I want to be able to set the message of the alert from a property of web control, in a similar way to the standard asp.net validation controls have the ErrorMessage property.

Can anyone advise me on the best way to splice this property into my embedded JavaScript?

Embedded js function

```
function checkDeduction(sender, eventArgs) {
    var dNewVal = eventArgs.get_newValue();
    if (dNewVal > 0) {
        var bRetVal = confirm("custom msg here");
        if (!bRetVal) {
           dNewVal = dNewVal * -1;
           sender.set_value(dNewVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a snippet of code, an example of the form you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this I added a custom attribute to my custom control on the PreRender event:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
        this.Attributes.Add("ErrorText", "custom error text from public prop");
        ...
        base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

I was then able to hold of the error message client-side like so:

```
confirm(sender.getAttribute('ErrorText'));
```

Job done!